How to fix Stretched faces caused by subdivision surface and shrinkwrap modifier?
I'm using Blender 4.2. i was trying to project my high resolution mesh on my retopolgized mesh using the method in this video: https://youtu.be/1CiQxc1QvRM?si=OPYpn4-RrJvG_UZq
But when i add a subdivision surface modifier parts of the geometry gets messed up and it still looks planar like in the picture bellow. (Around the ear.)

And when i add a shrinkwrap modifier, same parts go crazy and the corner of the eyes get stretched.


So I'm wondering why this happens and how to fix it. I'd appreciate any suggestions to solve this problem.
Here are the base mesh and the retopolgy:


Here's the .blend flie: 

Hi Gugoo, if you [edit] your question, you'll find a button to upload your .blend file. Could you please do that? I suspect bad geometry is the underlying problem, even though your mesh looks neat. I'm not sure what could cause the Shrinkwrap issue, though.

I suppose i can fix the stretching around the ears by retopologizing that area over again. But the stretching on the corner of the eyes is what has been bothering me for a while. It happens every time i retopologize a face. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried retopologizing the eyes again and it didn't work.

Hi. If you check the normals you will see a few red faces. The normals are flipped. This is causing the problem. Switch to Edit mode, select all vertices, and press Shift+N to Recalculate Outside

Thanks. That fixed the area around the ears but the eyes are still the same. Any ideas what could be the cause of it?

There is a level 3 Subdivision Surface modifier before the Shrinkwrap modifier. To apply the Shrinkwrap modifier you need to apply the Subdivision Surface modifier first because the stack works top-down. But this would add a lot more geometry. I would swap the order which also fixes the problems around the eyes. The ears will shrink a bit but that's just because there is not enough geometry, especially at the back of the ears. Add a few more loop cuts.
